# How Can I set different Constraint for different Screen sizes (For Ex: iPhone 3.5",4",4.7" and 5.5") using a single storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6

[image: I have tried for "Compact width,Any height option) but if I select an area as shown in the image then it will affect other screen size constraint too? For Ex: Constraint of 3.5" will affect constraint of 4",4.7" etc..]

I have searched it out, but not gotten any fruitful answers. I want to set different constraints for all different screen size in a single storyboard itself (Not programmatically).

How can I resolve this?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: I want to set different constraint for all screen size. For Ex: 130 constraint for 3.5" and 160 for 4" inch screen but dont let it happened programatically.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can adjust constraints based on device models without doing it programmatically. The size classes controls are there to set constraints for different (well) size classes. I think you would be better off setting constraints that are relative to the parent view (superview). You can set the dimensions to a certain percentage of the superview. You can read more about it here => http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/percentage-width-in-autolayout.html

Answer (score 0):

## Without writing a single line!

No need to write device based conditions these :-

```
if device == iPhoneSE { 
   constant = 44 
} else if device == iPhone6 {
   constant = 52
}
```

I created a library [Layout Helper](https://github.com/tryWabbit/Layout-Helper) so now you can update constraint for each device without writing a single line of code.

[image]

## Step 1

#### Assign the NSLayoutHelper to your constraint

[image]

## Step 2

#### Update the constraint for the device you want

[image]

## Step 3

#### Run the app and see the MAGIC

[image]